# How can I flash a zip programmatically from an app in android

Tags: java, android, shell, root, recovery

I'm trying to build an app which will automatically reboot recovery and flash a zip from my sd card.
This app can use system app permission since I am going to use it as a system app,
How can I do this?

I tried this code

```
   File zip = new File("/sdcard/test.zip");
    if(zip.exists()) {
        Toast.makeText(context,"ZIP EXIST!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("sh");
        OutputStream os = p.getOutputStream();
        os.write("mkdir -p /cache/recovery/\n".getBytes());
        os.write("echo 'boot-recovery' >/cache/recovery/command\n".getBytes());
        String cmd = "echo '--update_package=/sdcard/test.zip' >> /cache/recovery/command\n";
        os.write(cmd.getBytes());
        os.flush();

        // Trigger the reboot
        PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        powerManager.reboot("recovery");
    }
    else{
        Toast.makeText(context,"ZIP NOT EXIST!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

I also tried this code:

```
 Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/system/bin/sh");
    OutputStream os = p.getOutputStream();
    os.write("echo 'boot-recovery ' > /cache/recovery/command".getBytes());
    os.write("echo '--update_package=/sdcard/test.zip' >> /cache/recovery/command".getBytes());
    os.write("echo '--wipe_cache' >> /cache/recovery/command".getBytes());
    os.write("echo 'reboot' >> /cache/recovery/command".getBytes());
    os.write("reboot recovery".getBytes());

    os.flush();

       PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
                    powerManager.reboot("recovery");
```

But all it does is to reboot recovery, it does not flash my zip.
Please help.

P.S

I'm using android L on nexus 5 with TWRP recovery

Answer (score 1):

I believe that your problem is because different android version, In **JellyBean(4.1)** and later versions the *sdcard data* is placed in the directory `/storage/emulated/0` and the directory `/sdcard` which you are using refers to `/storage/emulated`, So, to get it to work, you have to change the directory to `/sdcard/0` which will makes the commands as the following:

- for your **first** way:

  ```
  String cmd = "echo '--update_package=/sdcard/0/test.zip' >> /cache/recovery/command\n";
  ```
- for your **second** way:

  ```
  os.write("echo '--update_package=/sdcard/0/test.zip' >> /cache/recovery/command".getBytes());
  ```